# micro SD light not working

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, noobs

I just got my raspberry pi 3 model B and the green light is not working. I need help fixing it. I tried reseting the card and putting noobs back on the micro SD, but it does not work. I need help.

Comment: Which model Pi? Do any of the LED's light up (including the Ethernet ports)? How are you powering the Pi? Have you tried burning Raspbian directly to the card? How are you burning the image to the card? Please edit your question and add these details.

Answer (score 0):

If green light is not blinking it means you need better power supply. Raspberry pi should be plugged into at least 2 amps of power. If you are using phone charger now, please try using tablet charger - it should be enough.

Comment: The activity LED has NOTHING to do with power (unless it is so low that nothing works).

Comment: PS Power is **NOT** measured in amps. You **NEED** 5V.

Comment: True, my mistake. I was thinking about power led that won't work if you won't give enough amps. And also correct power is measured in volts, 5V 2A from usb needed for raspberry.